# Moving Tensorflow 1x to Tensorflow 2x

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, machine-learning, tensorflow2.0

I have a big problem, because i'm learning tensorflow 1x for my final project. but now I don't understand the philosophy of tensorflow 2x. For example in a book writhe the next example:

```
import tensorflow as tf

sess = tf.Session()

import numpy as np

x_vals = np.array([1., 3., 5., 7., 9.])

x_data = tf.placeholder(tf.float32)

m_const = tf.constant(3.)

my_product = tf.mul(x_data, m_const)

for x_val in x_vals:

 print(sess.run(my_product, feed_dict={x_data: x_val}))
```

How to change this code in tensorflow 2x? Are there book about this philosophy (Pass tensorflow 1x to 2x)?

Comment: Have you done any research?

Comment: https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/migrate